# How do you discover databases?

Tags: research-process, databases

Is there a database or search engine where I can search for databases on a specific topic? For example, how do librarians decide which databases they will subscribe to; is there some central list?

Comment: You mean domain-specific databases listing publications, like Pubmed or Mathscinet or EconPapers?

Comment: If there is one, how do you discover it?

Comment: I just checked the university library near where I live and using a link that is prominently displayed on its homepage, I found [this list of 996 databases](http://guides.lib.uiowa.edu/az.php), which can be filtered according to subject and/or type and/or provider. I also looked at three other library web pages (well known, but otherwise chosen without much thought) --- Harvard Univ. and Princeton Univ. and Univ. of Michigan --- and in each case I had no trouble in finding a similar list of databases (or at least ways of finding those for a specified academic field).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thanks, that is helpful, although it wouldn't show me databases that exist but which my library hasn't subscribed to, but now I no longer believe that to be important since these lists are ample

Comment: For what it's worth, your first question only asked how to find databases on a specific topic, and my suggestion (which I probably did not make explicit enough) is that one method is to visit a lot of library web pages and then collect together all the databases you find at these various libraries on that topic. You might try libraries in different countries, as there might be some lesser (relative to the U.S.) known (or lesser listed) databases that you'll find than what searching only U.S. libraries will give, especially in China (but this probably won't help if you can't read Chinese).